# Multi Silverlight databinding

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

Does anyone know if its possible to do a binding and (if not how to achieve the same effect) on the same property using more than one binding in sort of a template

i.e.
A textblock that has Text bound in the expression

```
"{Binding Path=Contact.Title} {Binding Path=Contact.Firstname} {Binding Path=Contact.Surname}"
```

all in one text property

Answer (score 6):

Not a big deal just:

```
<TextBlock>
<Run Text="{Binding Path=Contact.Title}"/>
<Run Text="{Binding Path=Contact.Firstname}"/>
<Run Text="{Binding Path=Contact.Surname}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This works in Silverlight 5.  The original question was probably for Silverlight 2 or maybe 3.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it's not possible.

This is one of the reasons to follow the MVVM pattern, create an intermediary view which reflects the data in a format that you actually want presented, so you would create a fullname property on that class that was a concatenation of those fields and then bind to that.

Comment: It is possible via the workaround from Andrew, but I completely agree with you. Just expose the correct property in your ViewModel (if you're following the pattern) and remove the requirement for a multi binding and any converters along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Value Converters are one solution for binding to multiple values:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx#11262

In that scenario you'd bind your TextBlock's Text property to the Contact object and specify a custom value converter that you've created.  The converter can perform the string formatting based on property values.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because you won't get targeted change notifications on the Contact object when there are changes in the values of the *specific fields* you're binding to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do it directly in xaml.  I would absolutely love multiple bindings to one property.

What I have learned however, is that you can accomplish things similar to this using a couple different strategies:

Using a Stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">    
    <TextBlock Text="Hello,  "/>    
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact.Title}"/>    
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact.Firstname}"/> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact.Surname}"/> 
    <TextBlock Text="!"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

Using a Converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact, 
                  Converter={StaticResource ContactNameConverter}}"/>
```

[More Info On Converters](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)